# jakarta.persistence.Query is in unnamed module of loader 'jakarta.persistence.api@3.1.0'

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, wildfly

Above error is coming when I am migrating the application from JBoss 7.4 to WildFly 29.0 where I upgraded Spring framework to 6.0.11 and Hibernate to 6.2.6

Comment: That's not much to go on. Are you including Jakarta Persistence in your deployment? If so I would try removing that first. A stack trace would be helpful as well.